# javascript query selector to select specific elements

Tags: javascript

I have a querySelector that works. I want to show an element that does not have a specific class. I can display it if the class is there, but if v2l-hidden is there...I do not want to show it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".v2l-fileinput-filelist .include-warning")[0].innerHTML
```

```html
<ul class="v2l-fileinput-filelist">
<li id="d2l_3_0_437" data-v2l-name="assdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">1</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_427" data-v2l-name="adsdassdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">2</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_457" data-v2l-name="f.jpg" class="include-warning">3</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_47" data-v2l-name="ssdf.jpg" class="include-warning">4</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

So only 3 and 4 should show. Not all!

Comment: I have no idea what your actually trying to do.

Comment: Does your `v21-hidden` not have display:nona?   Or are you talking about just the resulting list?  You can just tell it to not include items with that specific class

Comment: *"So only 3 and 4 should show. Not all!"* - So add `display: none;` to the CSS for `.v2l-hidden`?  It's not clear to me how JavaScript is involved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an idea is to select all li that have this class and hide it by css or js

with js

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".v2l-fileinput-filelist .v2l-hidden")].forEach(hiddenElem => hiddenElem.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<ul class="v2l-fileinput-filelist">
<li id="d2l_3_0_437" data-v2l-name="assdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">1</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_427" data-v2l-name="adsdassdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">2</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_457" data-v2l-name="f.jpg" class="include-warning">3</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_47" data-v2l-name="ssdf.jpg" class="include-warning">4</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

but here js is not mandatorry and you can do the same with only css

```css
.v2l-fileinput-filelist .v2l-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="v2l-fileinput-filelist">
<li id="d2l_3_0_437" data-v2l-name="assdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">1</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_427" data-v2l-name="adsdassdf.jpg" class="include-warning v2l-hidden">2</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_457" data-v2l-name="f.jpg" class="include-warning">3</li>
<li id="d2l_3_0_47" data-v2l-name="ssdf.jpg" class="include-warning">4</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```